# Proper way to populate a controller with data from a factory?

Tags: angularjs

I have an Angular factory that is simply using the `$http` service to get data from a static json file on a server.

```
module.factory('ShowsProvider', function ($http) {
    return {
        get: function () {
            return $http.get('/static/shows.json');
        }
    };
});
```

I then have a controller that injects this factory, and calls its `get()` method defined above.

```
module.controller('RegisterController', ['ShowsProvider', function (ShowsProvider) {
    var vm = this;
    vm.shows = [];

    ShowsProvider.get().then(function (shows) {
        vm.shows = shows.data;
    });
}]);
```

This works, but it feels awkward to have a free-floating function call in my controller like this. Is there some sort of pattern in Angular to more cleanly call this factory, and provide the data to my Controller? Or is what I have an "acceptable" approach?

Comment: It's acceptable - you can always wrap that call in a function that gets called - but other than that, it's a-okay. You can also extend the `.then()` to be called at the service layer in case there's any data massaging to be done.

Comment: You might like $resource a little better, but you're still basically stuck with function calls somewhere.

Comment: Always good to resolve promise in the controller. If you have to do some pre treatment you can add little logic in the factory like discribet in this best practice -> https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide/blob/master/a1/README.md#data-services

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to handle this when using ngRoute or UI Router. The router takes the duty of unwrapping resolver promises, state/route resolvers are injected as resolved values into state/route controller.

```
$routeProvider.when('...', {
  resolve: {
    showsResolver: (ShowsProvider) => ShowsProvider.get()
  },
  controller: function (showsResolver) {
    this.shows = showsResolver;
  }
  ...
```

It is one of the reasons to use a router even in small application. If this isn't an option, then the original approach is the suggested way to unwrap promises in controller.

Answer (score 1):

Of course it's acceptable to call factory function like yours.

I generally wrap this kind of floating function inside an [IIFE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immediately-invoked_function_expression)(Immediately-Invoked Function Expression).

```
module.controller('RegisterController', ['ShowsProvider', function (ShowsProvider) {
    var vm = this;
    vm.shows = [];

    (function() {
        ShowsProvider.get().then(function (shows) {
                vm.shows = shows.data;
        });
    })();
}]);
```

This IIFE is executed when the controller loads. But, sometimes it happens that, I need to call a free floating function again(e.g after performing some `ng-click` operation etc). That's why, I keep this free floating function inside an anonymous function assigning to a variable. So, it helps you to call while controller loads or after controller loads.

```
module.controller('RegisterController', ['ShowsProvider', function (ShowsProvider) {
    var vm = this;
    vm.shows = [];

    vm.getShows = function() {
        ShowsProvider.get().then(function (shows) {
                vm.shows = shows.data;
        });
    }

    // suppose some ng-click operation calls this
    vm.deleteShow = function(show) {
        // suppose a deleteShow function is there in ShowsProvider
        ShowsProvider.deleteShow({showId: show.id}).then(function (shows) {
            // if you want to retrieve the shows again    
            vm.getShows();
        });   
    }

    (function() {
        vm.getShows();
    })();
}]);
```

There are some other good techniques also. But, it all comes down to what favors you.